# Micronaut Controller How To Return A No Content Response Status

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-aws

I'm learning Micronaut for our app that will be deployed to AWS Lambda. One of the endpoint needs to return a No Content. I tried different approaches but still not getting no content response.

This one returns 404 Not Found on localhost:8080

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Get
    public HttpResponse<Void> save() {
        return HttpResponse.noContent();
    }

}
```

Also this one

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Get
    @Status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void save() {
        
    }
}
```

I tried @Post but it returns

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input`

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Post
    @Status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void save() {
        
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide a working example. Thank you.

Comment: Does `return HttpResponse.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)` work?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown It has something to do with my build I guess.
On the build.gradle file I changed this line `runtime("lambda")` to `runtime("netty")` and it works now.

Comment: @berty Can you post that as an answer and mark it as the correct one, since that would help other people who are looking for a similar solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with the runtime specified on the build.gradle. I forgot to change it from `runtime("lambda")` to `runtime("netty")`, that's why testing it locally returns an error response.